# Perfoming SQL query or stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have some data that looks like this:

```
***listing_id,log_date,event***
2112,<date>,stage_1
2112,<date>,stage_2
2112,<date>,sold
2113,<date>,stage_1
2113,<date>,stage_6
2114,<date>,stage_1
2114,<date>,sold
```

I want to get listing_id, the duration(max_date - min_date) for which it is listed in case it's sold.

How do I achieve these reuslts when my data store is a MS SQL server?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Questions like "how to do this" without showing any attempt or effort are usually not welcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY and DATEDIFF along with a few CASE should do

```
select
    listing_id,
    datediff(dd, min(log_date),
        case
            when count(case when event = 'sold' then 1 end) > 0 then
                max(case when event = 'sold' then log_date end)
            else
                max(log_date)
        end
    ) duration,
    case 
        when count(case when event = 'sold' then 1 end) > 0 then 
            'Yes'
        else
            'No'
    end was_sold
from your_table
group by
    listing_id
;
```

You can use the below if you want to get the earliest sold date

```
min(case when event = 'sold' then log_date end)
```

`datediff(dd,....)` return difference in days. For more info, check [this out](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. But there are two more minor requirements.1) I want to have the status column (whether "Sold" is present or not).2)If sold is present , I want to consider date present in sold row as the max date, it needn't be global max. Please consider.

Comment: @user4654 - Updated. Can you try it?

Comment: let me try now.

Comment: Works with an issue . With this query I m able to get the latest "Sold" date, but it will be helpful to get the date corresponding to earliest sale. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use min(case...) Instead

Answer (score 0):

Not really enough detail in your question so I am guessing but maybe something like;

```
SELECT 
    listing_id,
    MIN(log_date) AS Start,
    MAX(log_date) AS Finish,
    datediff(day, MIN(log_date), MAX(log_date) AS Duration
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY 
    listing_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me clarify.  1) "Sold" may or may not occur for a listing. 2) If it doesn't occur , we just want the diff between the min and max dates. 3) In case "Sold" is present, it may occur in the final step or in the middle steps as well. If its the middle step, we just want to consider middle steps' date as max date.